# c# listbox not filling

Tags: c#, sql, combobox, listbox

I searched similar questions but none of them applyed to my situation.
So i have a listbox witch is supposed to fill with data depending on a selected item from a combobox.
The code worked fine but because of some changes made in the software i had to create a new form, copy/paste the design and the code to the new form. 
I made the necessary adjustments but now, all the comboboxes fill and the listbox wont.
Can anyoe say why, the code is:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using XXXXX.bin;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.IO;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Linq;


namespace XXXXX
{
    public partial class vidro : Form
    {
        public static SqlConnection con = Globais.GetDbConection();
        public vidro()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void vidro_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlDataAdapter SDA = new SqlDataAdapter("select distinct desempenho from vidros", con);
            DataTable DTT = new DataTable();
            SDA.Fill(DTT);
            desempenho.Items.Clear();
            foreach (DataRow ROW in DTT.Rows)
            {
                desempenho.Items.Add(ROW["desempenho"].ToString());
            }

            SqlDataAdapter SDA2 = new SqlDataAdapter("select distinct valu from vidros", con);
            DataTable DTT2 = new DataTable();
            SDA2.Fill(DTT2);
            valu.Items.Clear();
            foreach (DataRow ROW in DTT2.Rows)
            {
                valu.Items.Add(ROW["valu"].ToString());
            }

            SqlDataAdapter SDA3 = new SqlDataAdapter("select distinct fs from vidros", con);
            DataTable DTT3 = new DataTable();
            SDA3.Fill(DTT3);
            fsolar.Items.Clear();
            foreach (DataRow ROW in DTT3.Rows)
            {
                fsolar.Items.Add(ROW["fs"].ToString());
            }

            SqlDataAdapter SDA4 = new SqlDataAdapter("select distinct sel from vidros", con);
            DataTable DTT4 = new DataTable();
            SDA4.Fill(DTT4);
            select.Items.Clear();
            foreach (DataRow ROW in DTT4.Rows)
            {
                select.Items.Add(ROW["sel"].ToString());
            }

            SqlDataAdapter SDA5 = new SqlDataAdapter("select distinct compo from vidros", con);
            DataTable DTT5 = new DataTable();
            SDA5.Fill(DTT5);
            select.Items.Clear();
            foreach (DataRow ROW in DTT5.Rows)
            {
                compo.Items.Add(ROW["compo"].ToString());
            }
            SqlDataAdapter SDA6 = new SqlDataAdapter("select distinct sel from vidros", con);
            DataTable DTT6 = new DataTable();
            SDA6.Fill(DTT6);
            select.Items.Clear();
            foreach (DataRow ROW in DTT6.Rows)
            {
                select.Items.Add(ROW["sel"].ToString());
            }
        }
        private void desempenho_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            FillData();
        }
        private void valu_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            FillData();
        }
        private void fsolar_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            FillData();
        }
        private void selec_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            FillData();
        }
        private void compo_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            FillData();
        }
        private void FillData()
        {
            string combo1value = desempenho.Text;
            string combo2value = valu.Text;
            string combo3value = fsolar.Text;
            string combo4value = select.Text;
            string combo5value = compo.Text;

            string query = "select [desc],[enchimento],[compo] from vidros where 1=1 ";
            string queryWhere = "";
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.Connection = con;
            sda.SelectCommand = cmd;

            if (combo1value != "")
            {
                queryWhere += " and desempenho = @emp ";
                sda.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@emp", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = combo1value;
            }
            if (combo2value != "")
            {
                queryWhere += " and valu = @emp2 ";
                sda.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@emp2", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = combo2value;
            }
            if (combo3value != "")
            {
                queryWhere += " and fs = @emp3 ";
                sda.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@emp3", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = combo3value;
            }
            if (combo4value != "")
            {
                queryWhere += " and sel = @emp4 ";
                sda.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@emp4", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = combo4value;
            }
            if (combo5value != "")
            {
                queryWhere += " and compo = @emp5 ";
                sda.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@emp5", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = combo5value;
            }

            sda.SelectCommand.CommandText = query + queryWhere;

            DataTable DTT = new DataTable();

            sda.Fill(DTT);
            listView1.Items.Clear();
            for (int i = 0; i < DTT.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                DataRow dr = DTT.Rows[i];
                ListViewItem listitem = new ListViewItem(dr["desc"].ToString());
                listitem.SubItems.Add(dr["enchimento"].ToString());
                listitem.SubItems.Add(dr["compo"].ToString());
                listView1.Items.Add(listitem);
            }
        }
```

Comment: If everythings the same and you copied it over is it possible you forgot to hook up the event handlers to the combobox's?

Comment: @EpicKip hi, that was it, thanks, please answer and ill select your post as answer.

Comment: Glad it was an easy fix, posted a general answer for people that recreated their form too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you transferred the code to a new form you will need to hook up your event handlers for the controls.

This can be done in the designer by selecting a control and going to its event tab (the lightning shape near properties)
[image]

Or in code by doing: `controlName.EventName += eventHandlerMethodName;`
Example: `button1.Click += button1_Click;`

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that the control names(ComboBox and Listbox) are the same as in the copied code and add eventlisteners for each control after that.